# hypergeometric distribution for presence absence data in ecology

Tags: probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function

This is my first question to this site. I am new to ecology, have done maths degree many years ago, now studying masters in computational ecology, trying to get to grips with some equations for modelling species with presence absence data.
Can someone please confirm if I've got this right.

Say you take a set of $n$ samples over an area  which could contain $N$ samples of that size. You find a species to be present in $i$ of these samples when it actually has an occurrence of $j$ over the full extent $ N$.  The probability of  finding the occurrence $i$ is
$$P = \frac{{j \choose i}{N-j \choose n-i}}{N \choose n}$$

Thank you for your help. Hope my formatting is right.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the recursive definition of the probability:

$$P(m,k)=\begin{cases}0, & k>m \vee k>j, \\ 1, & m=0,\\
P(m-1,k) \frac{j-k}{N-m+1} +P(m-1,k-1) \frac{N+k -j -1}{N-m+1}, &0\leq k \leq \min(j,m) \wedge m>0\end{cases}$$
where $m$ is the number of samples taken, $k$ is the number of samples taken and containing the species.